# Ubuntu Software Center is crashing while trying to install psychonauts

Tags: 12.04, software-center

I am having a problem installing Tim Schafers epic platform video game Psychonauts trough the Ubuntu Software Center.

I have bought the game on http://www.humblebundle.com/ and I have used the new redeem option introduced in this bundle: "redeem your bundle on the Ubuntu Software Center."

When I have downloaded approximately 2.1 GB of Psychonauts then Ubuntu Software Center starts to repeatedly crash and pop-up with a new crash report dialog every few seconds (before previous ones are closed and that will crash the computer after a few min, unless I stop the download).

I also have a file-size bug, where Ubuntu Software Center tells me that I have downloaded 880,2 MB out of 133,3 MB

I use the new Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Ubuntu Software Center version 5.2.2.2 (©2009-2011 Canonical <--- That is also a bug, should be 2012 I guess)

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. [Report](http://askubuntu.com/a/5126/10698) it please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Keeping ignoring the pop-up windows did not stop the installation. Psychonauts finally got installed and only at that moment I closed the Software Center and the bug windows.

Comment: Don't hesitate to upvote answers, so that it may help other users too. Thank you! I hope that this bug will be fixed soon.